# ASP.NET MVC 3 Custom Exception Filter OnException Doesn't Fire

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 3 project and I want to implement my custom error handling logic. I'm trying to this by extending HandleErrorAttribute like this :

```
public class ErrorHandlingAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult { 
                                                    Data = new { success = false, error = filterContext.Exception.ToString() }, 
                                                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet 
                                                  };
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

What I need is, after some AJAX calls, to show some error message (by rendering a partial view) on a modal popup dialog. So, in the OnException method, I set the ExceptionContext's result as a JsonResult (I'm not rendering the partialview to string right now, I'll do that later)

My controller action is like below (I have decorated it with my custom filter):

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ErrorHandling]
 public JsonResult Create(StopEditViewModel viewModel)
 {
        Stop stop = Mapper.Map<StopViewModel, Stop>(viewModel.Stop);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Stop addedStop = _testFacade.AddStop(stop);

            return Json(new { success = true, tableContainer = _tableName }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }

        return Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
 }
```

After doing some research, I found that I need to remove `filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());` line from the RegisterGlobalFilters method in Global.asax. I did that too.

My web.config file has `<customErrors mode="On" />` tag.

But when I call the Create POST action, if an exception occurs, the custom filter method is not invoked. The application crashes. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Deniz have you call this by using Ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can catch Exception **OnFailure** method  in ajax option

```
In View
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SomeAction", new AjaxOptions { OnFailure = "handleAjaxError" }))
{

}

function handleAjaxError(ajaxContext) {
     alert("Request failed, status code ");
}
```

when you call action using Ajax it return within method.

Comment: Shivkumar, thank you for your answer. My point is that I want to avoid repetitive error handling code as much as possible. And I need it for all my controller actions, not just for ajax forms. So i decided to write a custom exception filter. I could wrap the code in every controller action with a try catch block and return some JsonResult exposing the error message, but I would like to do it by adding an exception filter, if possible.

Comment: if you call the action by using Ajax or java script then it will not invoke any filter. because it return value within calling function. oR your "handleAjaxError" function will catch all ajax exception so there is no any need to write separate Exception method for each ajax call.let me know if i can help you any more..

Comment: Ok then, I think I have to go on with your way. Thank you.